# How to append Serialized Numbers in ZPL II for a barcode?

Tags: barcode, zpl, zpl-ii

I'm trying to create a series of labels with a 128 Barcode that has as its information two serialized numbers that increment with every label printed. I can create the counters no problem but I can't append the information so it prints as the Barcode.

```
^FX Third section with bar code.
^BY10,2
^FO70,740^BC N,130,Y,N,N,A^FDto sort^FS

^FX Serial Numbers
^CF0,90
^FO70,940^FDSeals:^FS
^CFB,70
^FO300,940^SN2647001,100,^FS
^CF0,90
^FO780,940^FDTo:^FS
^CFB,70
^FO920,940^SN2647100,100^FS

^FX Labels
^PQ5
```

Comment: I copied your `SN^` instead of the to `sort` and [it worked](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=4&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EFO70%2C740%5EBC%20N%2C130%2CY%2CN%2CN%2CA%5EFD%5ESN2647001%2C100%5EFS%0A%5EPQ5%0A%0A%5EXZ). What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I want to make the two serialized numbers to read within the same barcode.

For example,

2467001 - 2467100

instead of just

2467001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `^SF` command.  It uses `^FD` to seed the serialization, and a mask for formatting.  For your example usage:

```
^FD2647001-2647000^SFddddddd%ddddddd,100%0000100^FS
```

Comment: That [doesn't work](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=4&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EFO50%2C50%0A%5EBCN%2C130%2CY%2CN%2CN%2CA%5EFD2647001-2647100%5ESFddddddd%25ddddddd%2C100%25100%5EFS%0A%5EPQ5%0A%0A%5EXZ). Amusingly, `^SFddddddd%ddddddd,0000100%0000100^FS` does.

Comment: Try it again.  There was a problem in the mask.  Needed to pad with zeros.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't check the question until a minute ago when I finally got it to work. Ended up doing the same thing, changing it into an ```^SF``` instead of an ```^SN``` and padded the thing with 0s. It was my first time working with this language overall but thank you for the response!